# Accessing random array element in ZSH

Tags: shell, shell-script, zsh

I have ZSH as my primary shell, and I'm trying to randomise access to an array. I keep seeing `feh` called, but I don't have that command. I have `_feh`, but I don't know if it's the same thing. What is that command.

Here's the reference:

```
FILES=( .../files/* )
feh $FILES[$RANDOM%$#FILES+1]
```

Here is my testing:

```
test=(a b c); feh ${test[$RANDOM]}
```

I'm on OSX 10.10.x for reference. Ultimately I'll use this to randomise SSH access to some hosts that I have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`feh` is an image viewer, just ignore that part... you want just the second part.

Basically, to access a random array element you want something like `${arr[${ri}]}` where `ri` is `$(( $RANDOM % ${#arr[@]} + 1))` that is, `ri` is a random index of the array `arr`

Now, `$RANDOM % N` resolves to a random number from `0` to `N-1`. In this case `N` is the array length `${#arr[@]}` (number of elements) but since array indexing starts from `1` in `zsh` you have to add one ( `+ 1`) so that `$(( $RANDOM % ${#arr[@]} + 1 ))` returns a value from `1` to `N`.

So e.g. to print a random element of the array:

```
print -r -- ${arr[$(( $RANDOM % ${#arr[@]} + 1 ))]}
```

Or simply, as array indices are parsed as arithmetic expressions:

```
print -r -- "$arr[RANDOM % $#arr + 1]"
```

When using that csh-style syntax (when the expansion is not in braces), the quotes are necessary in order for `zsh` to parse the subscript; alternatively, this could be written `$arr[RANDOM%$#arr+1]` or `${arr[RANDOM % $#arr + 1]}` (ksh-style).

Comment: Is that last part still correct, about array indices parsed as arithmetic expressions?  I get a "invalid subscript" error.

Comment: @Michaël, see edit.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to shuffle the array. Here, for an array that is the result of a glob expansion that can be done with:

```
files=( .../files/*(noe['REPLY=$RANDOM']) )
feh $files # or $files[1]
```

Or

```
shuffle() REPLY=$RANDOME
files=( .../files/*(no+suffle) )
```

To shuffle an arbitrary array, one technique is to still use the `oe` or `o+` glob qualifier, with something like:

```
shuffled_array=( /(e['reply=("$array[@]")']no+shuffle) )
```

That is use the `e` qualifier to make up the glob expansion (here applied to `/`) by setting `$reply` there, and then sort it with `o+`.