# In ZSH, what arithmetic expressions can appear as array subscript?

Tags: zsh, array, arithmetic

The ZSH manual (`zshparam(1)`) reads:

```
Array Subscripts
       Individual elements of an array may be selected using a subscript.  A
       subscript of the form `[exp]' selects the single element exp, where
       exp is an arithmetic expression which will be subject to arithmetic
       expansion as if it were surrounded by `$((...))'.
```

However, this quickly fails:

```
mc% arr=(a b c d e)     
mc% echo $arr[$#arr]    
e
mc% echo $arr[$(($#arr))]
e
mc% echo $arr[$(($#arr - 1))]
d
mc% echo $arr[$#arr - 1]  
zsh: invalid subscript
```

**Question:** Why, and what are the exceptions?

*Note:* this question stems from [don_crissti's answer there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287330/accessing-random-array-element-in-zsh), where they suggest `$arr[RANDOM % $#arr + 1]` to access a random element, but this throws up the above error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, any expression can appear as a subscript. The problem is getting the parser to put what you want in the subscript. Some characters, including spaces, never make it. Only word constituent characters can be part of the subscript, because the subscript is part of a word.

```
mc% echo $arr[ 1]       
zsh: invalid subscript
mc% echo $arr[1 ]
zsh: invalid subscript
mc% echo $arr[$#arr - 1]
zsh: invalid subscript
mc% echo $arr[$#arr-1]
d
```

The subscript parser stops at the first invalid character, and the “invalid subscript” error is triggered before zsh even checks for the terminating close bracket.

```
mc% echo $arr[ 1  
zsh: invalid subscript
```

In `echo $arr[ 1]`, the part after the space is in fact considered a separate word: `echo` would receive two arguments resulting from the expansion of `$arr[` and `1]`, except that zsh does not start executing any command due to the parsing failure. There are a few cases where you can tell that what you might think of as part of the arithmetic expression is in fact not parsed as such, for example:

```
mc% echo $arr[1<<2]   
heredoc> << is a heredoc operator, not part of the subscript.
heredoc> 2]
zsh: invalid subscript
```

Non-word-constituent characters can of course sneak in as part of a nested expansion such as an arithmetic expression or a command substitution.

```
mc% echo $arr[$[1&3]] 
a
mc% echo $arr[`echo "1 + 2"`]  
c
```

If the parameter expansion is in double quotes, any character (apart from a balanced closing bracket or an end quote) goes through to be part of the subscript. That's because inside double quotes, any character is effectively a word constituent character. Likewise, if the parameter expansion uses braces, zsh looks for the closing brace `}` for the parameter expansion before it looks for the closing bracket `]` for the subscript, and so non-word-constituent characters do make it into the subscript.

```
mc% echo "$arr[$#arr - 1]"
d
mc% echo ${arr[$#arr - 1]}
d
```

If you want to dive into the nitty-gritty details, the relevant function is [`parse_subscript`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/zsh-5.8/Src/lex.c#L1646), called from [`getindex`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/zsh-5.8/Src/params.c#L1847).

Comment: Zsh just lost some points in my eyes for not including the part it tries to interpret as the subscript in the error message. Or even saying, "missing ]"

Comment: Ah! Completely obvious now that you spell it out Gilles, thanks so much!

Comment: You can use the `${arr[ ... ]}` Korn syntax (as opposed to the `$arr[...]` csh syntax) to avoid those issues. The ability to use arithmetic expressions here is inherited from ksh. csh didn't allow it.